# Nginx: location directive for sub domains under a single server

Tags: nginx

I have a server config like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.site.com;
    server_name  stage.site.com;
    server_name  nagios.site.com;

    location ~* (.*)nagios {
        auth_basic "Admin";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

When I try to apply a location directive to the sub domain it does not seem to work.

I don’t want to duplicate server. It’s a lot of code.

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to apply a location directive to the sub domain it does not
>   seem to work.

`location` directive is used for URI, not sub domain.

> I don’t want to duplicate server. It’s a lot of code.

But it is the **right** way to do this. Checking `$http_host` with `if` directive is [not recommend](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html), either.

Comment: You can put all the common bits into a separate file and [include](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#include) it in each server block to avoid copy/pasting.